# Try to open a container with Docker (Mac) and receive: localhost cannot currently process this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: docker, macos

After building the container and checking that it runs, I try to access localhost:8080, but there are server errors and I can't understand why. the container log is the following:

```
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Starting SSH +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ SSH started +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Invoke Wordpress variables +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Variables invoked +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Starting Memcached +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 Starting memcached: memcached.
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Memcached started +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Starting Redis Cache +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 Starting redis-server: redis-server.
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Redis Cache started +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 +++ Starting PHP-FPM & Nginx +++
2024-02-14 10:18:40 sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'
2024-02-14 10:18:40 sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
2024-02-14 10:18:40 [14-Feb-2024 09:18:40] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 61
2024-02-14 10:18:40 [14-Feb-2024 09:18:40] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2024-02-14 10:18:45 127.0.0.1 -  14/Feb/2024:09:18:45 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
2024-02-14 10:18:50 127.0.0.1 -  14/Feb/2024:09:18:50 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
```

I checked the environment variables and they seem to be set correctly, as does docker-compose.yml.

sed command:

```
EOL
cat /etc/motd

echo "+++ Starting SSH +++"
service ssh start
echo "+++ SSH started +++"

echo "+++ Invoke Wordpress variables +++"
sed -i "s/{DB_HOST}/$DB_HOST/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{DB_PORT}/$DB_PORT/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{DB_NAME}/$DB_NAME/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{DB_USER}/$DB_USER/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{DB_PASSWORD}/$DB_PASSWORD/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{WP_SENTRY_PHP_DSN}/$WP_SENTRY_PHP_DSN/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{WP_SENTRY_ENV}/$WP_SENTRY_ENV/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{JS_DSN}/$JS_DSN/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{WP_ROCKET_KEY}/$WP_ROCKET_KEY/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{WP_ROCKET_EMAIL}/$WP_ROCKET_EMAIL/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i "s/{WP_MIGRATE_DB_PRO_KEY}/$WP_MIGRATE_DB_PRO_KEY/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
echo "+++ Variables invoked +++"

echo "+++ Starting Memcached +++"
/etc/init.d/memcached start
echo "+++ Memcached started +++"

echo "+++ Starting Redis Cache +++"
/etc/init.d/redis-server start
echo "+++ Redis Cache started +++"

echo "+++ Starting PHP-FPM & Nginx +++"
php-fpm -D; nginx
```

After update of @kyrylo my log is the following:

```
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Starting SSH +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server: sshd.
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ SSH started +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Invoke Wordpress variables +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Variables invoked +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Starting Memcached +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 Starting memcached: memcached.
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Memcached started +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Starting Redis Cache +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 Starting redis-server: redis-server.
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Redis Cache started +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 +++ Starting PHP-FPM & Nginx +++
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{DB_HOST}/vd-db/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{DB_PORT}/3306/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{DB_NAME}/wordpress/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{DB_USER}/wordpress/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{DB_PASSWORD}/wordpress/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{WP_SENTRY_PHP_DSN}/https://afb8128af0ba4f4a928149435dec2828@o385243.ingest.sentry.io/5217635/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{WP_SENTRY_ENV}/localhost/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{JS_DSN}/https://afb8128af0ba4f4a928149435dec2828@o385243.ingest.sentry.io/5217635/g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{WP_ROCKET_KEY}//g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{WP_ROCKET_EMAIL}//g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 sed: can't read s/{WP_MIGRATE_DB_PRO_KEY}//g: No such file or directory
2024-02-14 13:22:42 [14-Feb-2024 12:22:42] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 61
2024-02-14 13:22:42 [14-Feb-2024 12:22:42] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
2024-02-14 13:23:20 127.0.0.1 -  14/Feb/2024:12:23:20 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
```

Comment: Please share more details. This question is tagged with dockerfile, but does not contain any such code. Also, it's tagged with macOS - so is this specific to Mac, but working on Linux or other systems?

Comment: This may depend on the actual credentials you're providing; is there any punctuation in them (especially slashes `/`)?  Do you know which specific commands are producing the errors?

Comment: Also, i updated the dockerfile. About Environment, it is specific to Mac, i have this problem on my machine, i suppose it may be due the setting here on the Mac

Comment: (Consider trying to reduce this to a [mcve].  For example, your VM-like setup is trying to start several background daemons, which is unusual in Docker; for purposes of this question, do you have the same problem if you delete their setups?  Do you have the same problem deleting the long string of `chmod` lines, or `ENV` variables?)

Comment: @DavidMaze if i try to build the container, it looks like that works, but after i try to open localhost:8080, where the container pointing, i receive the error

Comment: @DavidMaze tried to delete the env variables from config file and rebuilt the container, i ve the same log

Comment: Can you [edit] the question and delete the parts of the Dockerfile and script that are unnecessary for this specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `sed` script was meant to be run on a GNU/Linux machine.

`sed` on macOS has a slightly different syntax.

By providing an empty string as the argument to the `-i` flag, you're instructing `sed` not to create backup files.

This is portable:

```bash
sed -i '' "s/{DB_HOST}/$DB_HOST/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{DB_PORT}/$DB_PORT/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{DB_NAME}/$DB_NAME/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{DB_USER}/$DB_USER/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{DB_PASSWORD}/$DB_PASSWORD/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{WP_SENTRY_PHP_DSN}/$WP_SENTRY_PHP_DSN/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{WP_SENTRY_ENV}/$WP_SENTRY_ENV/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{JS_DSN}/$JS_DSN/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{WP_ROCKET_KEY}/$WP_ROCKET_KEY/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{WP_ROCKET_EMAIL}/$WP_ROCKET_EMAIL/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
sed -i '' "s/{WP_MIGRATE_DB_PRO_KEY}/$WP_MIGRATE_DB_PRO_KEY/g" /var/www/html/config/application.php
```

Comment: It doesnt work, i update the new log

Comment: So it made it past `echo "+++ Invoke Wordpress variables +++"`. The error you're seeing is a different one.

Comment: What are the `sed` commands for the `+++ Starting PHP-FPM & Nginx +++` step?

Comment: where can i find them? in this file there aren't @kyrylo

Comment: Looks like there aren't any sed commands there. I just realized.

`echo "+++ Starting PHP-FPM & Nginx +++"
php-fpm -D; nginx`

I am not really sure why you see `sed` errors after that line

Comment: It seems like your Docker container doesn't actually have your wordpress app

Comment: also, i changed the paths from `php-fpm -D; nginx` to `/usr/local/sbin/php-fpm -D; /usr/sbin/nginx`(i think absolute paths) and increment the increase disk space; now everything pass, but the error "can't read s..." is after `echo "+++ Invoke Wordpress variables +++"``

@kyrylo